# Know all the using USB bus number

Tags: 12.04, usb, usb-drive, lsusb

I have connected seven different devices to my system. Now I want to know all the bus used by that devices with bus number's and device name.

So how can I do this?

I have used the `*lsusb*` command. Following is the o/p of that command:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:6450 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
```

In the following output 001, 002, 001, 002,001,002,001,001,001. are the displayed number.

Is it bus number or any thing else?

Also one quick question can we increase USB port bandwidth?

Comment: `lsusb` command will does.

Comment: @ Avinash Raj, I have edit my question. Please what is your thought?